# Removing arbitrary contents ahead of an Iterator or List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, iterator

I have a use-case where I need to remove items from a `MutableList` or `Iterator` while iterating, including items ahead of the current iterator position.

To remove the current item from the iterator, the `Iterator.remove()` method can be used, but I'm unsure how to remove other items from the set to be iterated.

For example, if I wanted to remove the item with a value double that of the current item, and remove the current item if it is prime.

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

with(numbers.iterator()) {
    forEach { number -> 
        if (isPrime(number)) remove() // Remove current item if it is prime

        if (numbers.contains(2*number)) {
            /* Remove first instance of 2*number from the current iterator */
        }
    }
}
```

How would I do this in Kotlin avoiding a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

In this case the end result ought to just be `12` as 6 will be removed before being checked.

Comment: Why not make a new list without the numbers you don't want, instead of editing an existing list?

Comment: That would work too, if I could then use the new list for subsequent iterations?

Comment: What do you mean by subsequent iterations? I was thinking that you would do something along the lines of read from you iterator, and then either append to the new list, or not append to the iterator for n iterations. Imo iterators are not really a good fit for this kind of problem.

Comment: what about [filtering](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-filtering.html)?

Comment: @PiRocks Based on a condition, I need to seek ahead in the list and remove items that no longer need to be checked/listed. Rather than appending or not appending to a new list, I need to remove input data that can be discarded.

Comment: @TakumoK why do you want to filter out only the first occurrence of `2*number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your algorithm the result should be [1, 4, 9, 12] and not 12. 1 won't be removed as it is not a prime. 4 won't be removed as 2 was removed when processing 1. 9 won't be removed as there is no natural number which multiplied by 2 is 9. 12 won't be removed as 6 was removed when processing 3.

This code seems to work

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

with(numbers.iterator()) {
    val visited = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    forEach { number -> 
        if (number % 2 == 0 && visited.contains(number/2)) {
            remove()
        }
        else {
           visited.add(number)
           if (isPrime(number)) remove() 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this doesn't solve my exact use case, I'm going to accept this answer as it does answer the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is store enough information to know which elements to remove when you get to them. In this specific case:

```
with(numbers.iterator()) {
    val toRemove = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    forEach { number -> 
        // instead of contains because you only want the first instance of a number in the set to be removed
        if (toRemove.remove(number)) {
            remove()
        } else {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                remove() // Remove current item if it is prime
            }
            toRemove.add(2*number)
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat: this won't remove `2*number` if it's behind the current position of the iterator.

Comment: Yes, you are right (it was trying to remove the same element twice).